# count distinct non-empty strings which are subsequences of all four strings

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here is a [spoj problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CSUBSEQS/) which asks you to count distinct non-empty strings which are subsequences of all four strings  . For Example

```
Input:
 aabb
 abab
 baba
 acba

Output:
 4
The four sequences are "a", "b", "aa", and "ab".
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: oh! thanx for that awesome advice

Comment: I tried to built recurrence using approach of  LCS of two strings, but could not figure it out then .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order not to ruin the fun, I do not post a complete answer, but just give you some idea.

Write the four strings as `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.

For a non-negative integer `i`, write `A<i>` for the substring of `A` obtained by removing the first `i` letters. The same notation applies to `B<i>`, `C<i>`, `D<i>`.

For a letter `X` (from `a` to `z`) and four non-negative integers `i`, `j`, `k`, `l`, define `F(X, i, j, k, l)` to be the number of different common subsequences of `A<i>`, `B<j>`, `C<k>`, `D<l>` which start with the letter `X`.

Try to find a recurrence relation between these `F`. This gives a dynamic programming approach.

EDIT: More details here.

`F(X, i, j, k, l)` can be calculated as follows: let `i0` be the first index after `i` such that `A[i0] = X`. Let `j0`, `k0`, `l0` be similarly defined.

The indice `i0`, `j0`, `k0`, `l0` will be defined only if `X` occurs in all four substrings. Otherwise, it is clear that `F(X, i, j, k, l) = 0`.

Once the four indice are all defined, any common subsequence of `A<i>`, `B<j>`, `C<k>`, `D<l>` starting with `X` will be of the form `X s`, where `s` is a common subsequence of `A<i0>`, `B<j0>`, `C<k0>`, `D<l0>`. Hence the formula:

`F(X, i, j, k, l) = sum of all F(Y, i0, j0, k0, l0)`,

where the sum runs over all `Y` from `a` to `z`.

Last trick: use lazy propagation to avoid useless calculations.

Comment: thanx you @WhatsUp , you really made my day , here is my accepted code if any one needs furthur help http://ideone.com/AvliD4

Comment: @sumit In that case would you mind accepting the answer?